# How to trigger onClick event in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, onclick

I am new to python programming. I have to develop u use-case where I have 9 circles along the cicumference of a big circle. On click of any circle i have change its color. How do I do that in python? I have written code to draw the circles using tkinter.

```py
from tkinter import *
import math
root = Tk()
myCanvas = Canvas(root)
myCanvas.pack()

def create_circle(x, y, r, canvasName): #center coordinates, radius
    x0 = x - r
    y0 = y - r
    x1 = x + r
    y1 = y + r
    return canvasName.create_oval(x0, y0, x1, y1)

a= 150
b = 130

r = 100

for x in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]:
    angle = (2* x * 3.14) / 9
    xCoordinate = r * math.cos(angle) + a
    yCoordinate = r * math.sin(angle) + b
    create_circle(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, 20, myCanvas)
root.mainloop()
```

Current partial output:

[image]

Comment: Bind a click event to canvas. Then define a bounding box for every circle. Depending on the click position (x,y), you can determine which circle is clicked. Then you can change the color.

Comment: @Epsi95: that's more work than is necessary. the canvas has a way to find the closest object to a click.

Comment: Great, didn't know!

Comment: Have you done any research? There are lots of examples on the internet for clicking items on a canvas.

Comment: def key(event):
    print("pressed", repr(event.char)) and then myCanvas.bind("<Key>", key) . This doesnt work